# How to skip the current element of array in for loop in bash script?

Tags: arrays, bash, shell, for-loop

I have a array of IP addresses. While traversing the array, for each element in the current iteration, I need rest of the elements in the new array. I have tried this:

```
create_nodes_directories(){
        read -r CURRENTHOST _ < <(hostname -I)
        HOSTS=(192.168.110.165 192.168.110.166)
        for i in ${!HOSTS[*]} ; do

                        #Here I need array elements other than ${HOSTS[$i]}
                        #created new array args()
                        args=()

                        for j in ${!HOSTS[*]} ; do

                                if [["${HOSTS[$j]}" = "${HOSTS[$i]}"  ]]; then
                                        continue;
                                else
                                        args+=("${HOSTS[$j]}")

                                fi
                        done
                        args+=("$CURRENTHOST")

                        create_genesis_start_file ${args[*]}
        done
}
```

For each iteration I need array elements other than ${HOSTS[$i]}. I have tried to create new array `args` , compare the elements and adding rest of the array elements of `HOSTS`. `create_genesis_start_file` is the function whom I want to pass `args`. This code giving error while comparing `if [["${HOSTS[$j]}" = "${HOSTS[$i]}"  ]]; then` and also the args array is not as expected.
Error:

```
environment: line 79: [[192.168.110.165: command not found
environment: line 79: [[192.168.110.166: command not found
```

Expected output example:

```
if array HOSTS is,
HOSTS=(192.168.110.165 192.168.110.166 192.168.110.167)

for the first iteration, I need
args=(192.168.110.166 192.168.110.167)

for second iteration,
args=(192.168.110.165 192.168.110.167)
and so on. 

CURRENTHOST should be added always.
```

Please correct me.

Comment: You say "is not as expected", but you don't describe, what exactly is the content of it, as opposed to what you hope would be stored in it. BTW, did you try to trace your code with `set -x`?

Comment: `[["${` is an error. Please check your scripts with shellcheck `[["${HOSTS[$j]}" = "${HOSTS[$i]}"  ]];` - don't compare values, compare indexes. Just `if [[ "$i" != "$j" ]]` . The method is ok - it should work, only syntax errors are left for you to fix. And prefer `for i in "${!hosts[@]}"` to quote properly the indexes, and _prefer_ to use lowercase variables in your scripts, _not_ uppercase. As I'm curious, what system supports the `-I` argument to `hostname`?

Comment: @Varsh: Your code should produce a _command not found_ error, but you don't mention it.  Did you really post the exact code?

Comment: I edited the question please check. I didn't used `set -x`

Comment: Yes, so read the duplicate. `[["${` is an error. Check your script with http://shellcheck.net

Comment: Thank you @KamilCuk. The error is resolved. But where should I place `args+=("$CURRENTHOST") ` ? I need it in each set of array. I triend placing at the start and end of loop but it is not adding CURRENTHOST.